# Python and PyQt string can't print

Tags: python, encoding, printing, pyqt

So, I'm using Python with PyQt and I have a very strange problem. A string that prints OK at one point doesn't print OK after a few lines of code! Here's my code:

```
name = str(self.lineEdit.text().toUtf8())
        self.let_change = Search()
        name_no_ind = self.let_change.indentation(name)
        print(name_no_ind)
        name_cap = self.let_change.capital(name)
        name_low = self.let_change.lower(name)
        print(name_no_ind, name_cap, name_low)
        col = self.combobox.currentIndex()
        row = 0
        for i in range(0, self.tableWidget.rowCount()):
            try:
                find_no_ind = self.let_change.indentation(self.tableWidget.item(row, col).text())
                find_cap = self.let_change.capital(self.tableWidget.item(row, col).text())
                find_lower = self.let_change.lower(self.tableWidget.item(row, col).text())
                if name_no_ind or name_cap or name_low in find_no_ind or find_cap or find_lower:
                    self.tableWidget.setItemSelected(self.tableWidget.item(row, col), True)
                    print("Item found in %d, %d" % (row,col))
                row += 1
            except AttributeError:
                row += 1
```

And here's what I get:

```
Αντωνης
('\xce\x91\xce\xbd\xcf\x84\xcf\x89\xce\xbd\xce\xb7\xcf\x82', '\xce\x91\xce\x9d\xce\xa4\xcf\x8e\xce\x9d\xce\x97\xce\xa3', '\xce\xb1\xce\xbd\xcf\x84\xcf\x8e\xce\xbd\xce\xb7\xcf\x82')
Item found in 0, 0
```

Isn't that strange? It prints OK and then it doesn't. Does anybody know what can I do?

P.S.: Here are the functions:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
class Search():
    #A function that removes indentations: 
    def indentation(self, name):
        a = name
        b = ["ά", "Ά", "ή", "Ή", "ώ", "Ώ", "έ", "Έ", "ύ", "Ύ", "ί", "Ί", "ό", "Ό"] 
        c = ['α', 'Α', 'η', 'Η', 'ω', 'Ω', 'ε', 'Ε', 'υ', 'Υ', 'ι', 'Ι', 'ο', 'Ο']
        for i in b:
            a = a.replace(i, c[b.index(i)])
        return a

    # A function that makes letters capital:    
    def capital(self, name):
        a = name
        greek_small = ["α", "β", "γ", "δ", "ε", "ζ", "η", "θ", "ι", "κ", "λ", "μ", "ν", "ξ", "ο", "π", "ρ", "σ", "τ", "υ", "φ", "χ", "ψ", "ω", "ς"]
        greek_capital = ["Α", "Β", "Γ", "Δ", "Ε", "Ζ", "Η", "Θ", "Ι", "Κ", "Λ", "Μ", "Ν", "Ξ", "Ο", "Π", "Ρ", "Σ", "Τ", "Υ", "Φ", "Χ", "Ψ", "Ω", "Σ"]
        for i in greek_small:
            a = a.replace(i, greek_capital[greek_small.index(i)])
        return a
    #A function that makes letters lower:    
    def lower(self, name):
        a = name
        greek_small = ["α", "β", "γ", "δ", "ε", "ζ", "η", "θ", "ι", "κ", "λ", "μ", "ν", "ξ", "ο", "π", "ρ", "σ", "τ", "υ", "φ", "χ", "ψ", "ω", "ς"]
        greek_capital = ["Α", "Β", "Γ", "Δ", "Ε", "Ζ", "Η", "Θ", "Ι", "Κ", "Λ", "Μ", "Ν", "Ξ", "Ο", "Π", "Ρ", "Σ", "Τ", "Υ", "Φ", "Χ", "Ψ", "Ω", "Σ"]
        for i in greek_capital:
            a = a.replace(i, greek_small[greek_capital.index(i)])
        return a
```

Basically, it capitalizes or lowers Greek characters...

**SOLUTION!!!:**
Steve solved the initial problem and based on what he said, I came up with this that solves everything:

```
name = str(self.lineEdit.text().toUtf8())
        self.let_change = Search()
        name_no_ind = self.let_change.indentation(name)
        name_cap = self.let_change.capital(name)
        name_low = self.let_change.lower(name)
        name_list = [name, name_no_ind, name_cap, name_low]
        col = self.combobox.currentIndex()
        row = 0
        for i in range(0, self.tableWidget.rowCount()):
            try:
                item_ = str(self.tableWidget.item(row, col).text().toUtf8()) 
                find_no_ind = self.let_change.indentation(item_)
                find_cap = self.let_change.capital(item_)
                find_lower = self.let_change.lower(item_)
                item_list = [find_no_ind, find_cap, find_lower]
                for x in name_list:
                    for y in item_list:
                        if x in y:
                            self.tableWidget.setItemSelected(self.tableWidget.item(row, col), True)
                row += 1
            except AttributeError:
                row += 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that one r both of `self.let_change.capital(name)` or `self.let_change.lower(name)` is overwriting it by using the name of the input parameter or possibly changing the encoding.  Since you have not posted the code for them I can not be sure.

Sorry, they are not the problem.  The problem is that you are printing them differently:

```
>>> print(capital(name))
ΑΝΤΩΝΗΣ
>>> print(capital(name), name)
('\xce\x91\xce\x9d\xce\xa4\xce\xa9\xce\x9d\xce\x97\xce\xa3', '\xce\x91\xce\xbd\xcf\x84\xcf\x89\xce\xbd\xce\xb7\xcf\x82')
>>> print(capital(name))
ΑΝΤΩΝΗΣ
>>> print(name, name)
('\xce\x91\xce\xbd\xcf\x84\xcf\x89\xce\xbd\xce\xb7\xcf\x82', '\xce\x91\xce\xbd\xcf\x84\xcf\x89\xce\xbd\xce\xb7\xcf\x82')
>>> print(name,)
('\xce\x91\xce\xbd\xcf\x84\xcf\x89\xce\xbd\xce\xb7\xcf\x82',)
>>> print(name)
Αντωνης
>>> print("%s = %s" % (name, capital(name)))
Αντωνης = ΑΝΤΩΝΗΣ
>>>
```

So you either need separate print statements or the use of a format string.

Comment: You are right, but that is not the only problem: after that,(in the long sequence of or in or) it doesn't do the job it needs to do, it doesn't select only the items that have the strings in them, it selects all the items! I hope you understand what I'm trying to say, I doubt that I explained right...

Comment: Basically get rid of the or in or's - without brackets it is bad news - and just get the value from the cell, (as val say), use strip to get rid of any leading spaces the check if (val[0] in self.greek_capitials) or (val[0] in self.greek_lower) - I would move them both to the object level to avoid having one copy per function - only once you know that there is a string should you start processing it as a string.  BTW this is a separate problem and should be raised as a new question if that doesn't sort it out.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've uploaded the final code, only thing I had to do to solve my second problem was to separate them!